# Connected to VPN but not able to ping the host

Tags: vpn

At work, I'm connecting to our VPN using a wireless router. Everything works great and I have no problems. At home, I can make an initial connection and ping our servers, connect via RDP and such.

However, after a minute or so, the connection dies. The info in the task bar still says that I'm connected but pinging the servers give me timeout. I've also noticed that when I'm on the VPN, the internet isn't available. I have to disconnect from the VPN (not that I seem to be **on** it) and then surf places. (The last part could be due the internet traffic being directed through VPN, though.)

We've got fiber here and the brand of the modem is Dlink DIR-645 (it's the round one), hardware version A1, firmware 1.01.

I'm almost certain **it's my router and its settings** that are to blame. Tested on two computers (Win7 and Win8). When connecting via 4G-modem, I have no problems either.

I've read about MTU but it's already set to maximum 1500 so that's not it, either.
What can I do about it?
What more can I investigate?

EDIT:

I've found two more link that might be of interest as a reference. Sadly, there's no answer on how to solve my problem ([the first one](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/34646-17-windows-connects-successfully-ping-access-host)) or the suggestions doesn't work out in my case ([the second one](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/323289-13-looking-kind-home-small-business-server)).

Comment: Do you have another router to confirm the problem is actually with the router?

Comment: Yes, at work I'm connecting without any problems. It only occurs on **my** router and on **any** computer I've tested. The same computers work perfectly with other routers. I've tested all possible four cases. and the common denominator is the router.